# Cannot see some websites' HTTP requests in developer console network tab

Tags: google-chrome, http, developer-tools

If I press F12 in Chrome and go to the network tab, visit AI Dungeon and start a new story, I can't get any data past the first turn. In fact, when I check all the calls all I see is a bunch of "graphql". I went through each and every one of the "graphql" and the responses don't even contain anything remotely long enough to contain the text data, not even an obfuscated version of it. Yet I clearly see the new story text on my browser screen, such as

> You decide to pick up the stone anyway. "Hey, don't take that stone,
> it's mine," Jacob says in an irritated tone.

Where could the text be hiding and how is this physically possible?

Comment: "Where could the text be hiding" Javascript. "how is this physically possible" Javascript.

Comment: That is GPT-3, a huge AI model which cannot run on an end user computer! It can't be running via the browser itself. It had to get the text "Hey, don't take that stone, it's mine," from somewhere, right? So even if Javascript is doing something, wouldn't it need to call an endpoint at some point? And wouldn't the browser Network tab be able to detect this HTTP call?

Comment: @mashuptwice you got an upvote on your comment but still haven't explained how javascript on any old computer's browser could possibly run a huge AI text generation model which requires at minimum a powerful GPU if not several.

Comment: I've never said that Javascript is running the AI, but it is highly likely used to connect to the AIs API and handles how text is displayed in your browser. Probably the API doesn't use HTTP as protocol and even if it were the network monitor will only be able to show you **whole files** that are transferred.

Comment: I see, thanks. Would I need to delve into the javascript to see what's happening, or could some other tool such as Wireshark be able to reverse engineer what's being sent/received?

Comment: Try it and tell us.